# Conditionally select most common value in an array in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a table (only one row) in my PostgreSQL 9.5 db with two columns i.e., count (bigint) and array (text).

```
count     array
6         "112,19.3,142,142,19.3,172,172,20.3,202,202,20.3,232,232,19.3,262,262,19.3,292"
```

The array represents six (thus count = 6) set of values i.e., `Lower_limit`, `Value` and `Upper_limit`. Now, I need to conditionally modify my array i.e., when upper limit and lower limits are coinciding then select the first upper limit and last lower limit and return the most common value (which is 19.3) among the limits. My desired output would be like:

```
count    array
1        112, 19.3, 292
```

Could anyone help me to have some pointers towards my desired output?

Answer (score 1):

I must admin - I dont understand how you get count =1, but below is an example of how you can build array with firsrt, last and most common values. Mind if there would be several mos common values it would unpredictably pick on of em

```
t=#
with a(r) as (values(array[112,19.3,142,142,19.3,172,172,20.3,202,202,20.3,232,232,19.3,262,262,19.3,292]))
, p as (select * from a,unnest(a.r) with ordinality)
, t as (
select count(1) over (partition by unnest)
, unnest u
, r[1] a
, r[array_length(r,1)] e
from p
order by unnest
limit 1
)
select array[a,u,e]
from t
;
     array
----------------
 {112,19.3,292}
(1 row)
```

Comment: Count represents the six set of values (lower, value, upper) when we update our array based on coinciding upper and lower limits then isn't it possible to update count based on output? Like your query returned one set.

Comment: sorry - I don't follow - so the count would be 3?.. not one?.. I did not get why you have six in first place:)

Comment: Each count must contain three values. So probably we can count the array elements and update count in the last. Just an idea :)

Comment: ah,ok I think I get now - then my answer is wrong :)

Comment: combination of lower + value + upper makes count and how many values we have in array must be counted and here comes the update for count :) Probably your answer needs an update.